# strictly semifinite weights restrict to a von Neumann subalgebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $\omega$ is a strictly semi-finite weight on a von Neumann algebra $M$ and $N$ is the von Neumann subalgebra of $M$.

Is $\omega|_N$ a strictly semifinite weight on $N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Say $\omega$ is the canonical trace on $M = B(l^2)$ and $N \subset M$ is a type III factor.

Comment: Or, really, $N$ being any factor that’s not type I would be enough.

Comment: If $N$ is a type III factor, there does not exists a trace.

Comment: @mathbeginner Yeah…? Isn’t your question asking for a strictly semi-finite weight on $M$? $M = B(l^2)$ in this example, and there is a canonical trace on $B(l^2)$ which is semi-finite. It is only $N$ that is type III. The canonical trace on $B(l^2)$, restricted to $N$, is clearly not semi-finite, precisely because there’s no (semi-finite) trace on a type III factor. (Then again, everything not type I would do. If $N \subset B(l^2)$ is a factor that’s not type I, then every projection in $N$ has infinite rank, so under the canonical trace on $B(l^2)$, they all have infinite trace.)

Comment: @mathbeginner I guess you’re using $\omega$ to denote the weight. For some reason I typed in $\varphi$. Fixed.

Comment: If $\omega|_N$ is semifinite, does it means that $n_{\omega|_N}=\{x\in N:\omega|_N(x^*x)＜\infty\}$ is w-dense in $N$? What about the case when there exists a faithful normal conditional expectation from $M$ onto $N$, we still cannot conclude $\omega_N$ is strictly semifinite?

Comment: @mathbeginner Isn't your question about trying to prove $\omega|_N$ is *not* semifinite? I'm confused.

Comment: @mathbeginner Ah, wait, there's obvious counterexample even when there is a faithful normal conditional expectation. Just let $N = \mathbb{C} \subset B(l^2) = M$. Again, the canonical trace on $M$ does not restrict to a semi-finite weight on $N$, but there is a faithful normal conditional expectation, namely any faithful normal state. (If you do not want a finite-dimensional $N$, just tensor both $M$ and $N$ with an infinite-dimensional factor.)

Comment: Thanks! Is the above definition correct?

Comment: You mean $\omega$ is semifinite iff $\{x: \omega(x^\ast x) < \infty\}$ is weakly dense? If I recall correctly, yes, that is correct. That is only semifinite though. Strictly semifinite is a stronger condition. Though it is equivalent to semifinite if the weight is tracial.